# Django jinja if-elif statement breaks with ==

Tags: django, if-statement, conditional-statements, jinja2, django-3.0

So on my front-end, I want to show some HTML only if the user belongs to one of 2 groups: 'admins' or 'clerks'. There are 3 groups of users: 'admins', 'clerks', and 'sellers'. Here is my front-end code:

```
{% if user.groups.all.0 == "admins" %}
        <h1>Some HTML</h1>
{% elif user.groups.all.0 == "clerks" %}
        <h1>Some HTML</h1>
{% endif %}
```

When I run this code, the HTML shows for the admins. But that of the clerks does not show. I have tried printing out the group to be sure that the spelling and the casing were the same, and they were the same. And Django does not throw an error. It only works if I rewrite the code as follows:

```
{% if user.groups.all.0 == "admins" %}
        <h1>Some HTML</h1>
{% elif user.groups.all.0 != "sellers" %}
        <h1>Some HTML</h1>
{% endif %}
```

But I feel like this is not good design. Please am I missing something? Thank you all in advance

Comment: `user.groups.all` are a set of `Group` objects, so it makes no sense to compare these with a string.

Comment: But furthermore it is imho not good design. Especially since you use `.0`, so you check the *first* group. The order of the groups is arbitrary, so it is not said that a user has a group, has only one group, and that the first one will be admins or sellers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, is a not practical idea for too many reasons.
Think that using that method you are getting possibilities and processing that don't correspond to the templates. The templates engine philosophy is just basic and no important logic.
A way to have more control and more practical is using a flag. For example

```
groups_permited_for_this=["admins","clerks",...]

Permited =False
for group in user.Groups.all:
   if group.name in groups_permited_for_this:
        Permited =True
```

Pass it as context and then use a Jinja if statement.

Comment: That's looks like a nice way to do it. Although I solved it in a different way. I'll post it as a reply. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved the issue in a slightly different way from the one above:
First, I created a folder called 'templatetags' inside the app.
Then I created 2 files in it:

1. An empty '**init**.py' file
2. A 'cust_auth.py'(for custom authentication) file
   Inside the 'cust_auth.py' file I wrote a function that does a similar thing as in #Paulo Aguilar's answer above:

```py
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name):
    group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
    return True if group in user.groups.all() else False
```

Then in my template, I loaded the 'cust_auth.py' file at the top:

```
{% load auth_extras %}
```

Then I did the logic I was looking for:

```
{% if user|has_group:"admins" %}
<h1>Some HTML</h1>
{% endif %}
```

I preferred this because I think over the cause of my application, I will want more custom authentications
Thank you Paulo and whoever posts

Comment: Better: `def has_group(user, group_name): return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()`